# Get-ChildItem recursively but exclude files in the parent folder

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I need to get a list of files in all subdirectories of $PSScriptRoot but exclude any files in the parent folder of $PSScriptRoot.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could list the parent folders first, then recurse each directory for files:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot -Directory | Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `Where-Object` clause to filter out all files that are directly inside the $PSScriptRoot:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot -Recurse -File | Where-Object { $_.DirectoryName -ne $PSScriptRoot}
```

<sup>you can use switch `-File` instead of `Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer}` as of PowerShell version 3.0</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call Get-ChildItem again as a pipe

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Get-ChildItem
```

Comment: Thanks. I used ```$Files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer}```.  The files are being sent to a move-item loop and I don't want the subdirs themselves being moved.  Only the files in them.