# Choosing columns for merged files in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, import-csv

I am using get-childitem to recurse through directories ( skipping some at the top level ) open a series of csv files, append the filename to the end  each line of data
and combine the data into one.

```
$mergedData= Get-ChildItem $path -Exclude yesterday,"OHCC Extract",output | 
  Get-ChildItem  -recurse -Filter *csv  | 
  Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) } | 
  % {
      $file = $_.Name
      $fn = $_.FullName
## capture the header line 
    $FirstLine = Get-Content  $fn -TotalCount 1 
## add the column header for filename
    $header = $FirstLine + ",Filename"
## get the contents of the files without the first line
    Get-Content $fn  | SELECT -Skip 1   | %{ "$_,$file" }
    }
```

Now each file had 5 columns , ID, First Name , Last Name , Phone , Address.  The column names are surrounded by double quotes ( "ID", "First Name" ) .
The request is now to skip everything but the ID and the Last Name column. So I tried ( starting with just ID, will add First Name later)

```
 Get-Content $fn  | SELECT -Skip 1 -Property ID  | %{ "$_,$file" }
```

I get @{ID=} in the resulting file.

Then I tried

```
Get-Content $fn  | SELECT -Skip 1   | %{ $_.ID }
```

which yield blanks and then

```
Import-Csv -Path  $fn -Delimiter ',' | SELECT ID
```

Which gives @{ID=73aec2fe-6cb3-492e-a157-25e355ed9691}
At this point I am just flailing because I obviously don't know how to handle objects in PS.
I have PowerShell 5.1.19041.1682 on windows 10.
Thanks

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish by piping one Get-ChildItem to another. Could you add text to your answer laying out in prose what your are trying to accomplish?

Comment: You don’t seem to be initialising your ```$fn``` variable anywhere. Is this a typo in your question, or is it how your actual code is written?

Comment: Fixed the $fn variable. Had a lot of   debugging that I removed and accidently removed the initialising.  For the double Get-Childitem.  When you combine them like this  [ Get-ChildItem $path -Exclude yesterday,"OHCC Extract",output   -recurse -Filter *csv ]  , it doesn't exclude the directories. So the first child-item get the directories you want, and the second recurses them ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65565862/get-childitem-recursively-but-exclude-files-in-the-parent-folder )

Comment: It would help to have an example input file and the expected results generated from it…

Answer (score 0):

I was asked for sample data , so here it is. There are 35 files across multiple subdirectories

Input FileA

| column1 | ID | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| East | 12 | apple |
| west | 5 | pear |

Input FileB

| column1 | ID | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| East | 15 | kiwi |

### Output

| Column1 | column3 | Filename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| East | kiwi | FileB |
| East | apple | FileA |
| west | pear | FileB |

But I did figure it out myself . Working code

```
$path = "<directory where the files are located> "
$pathout = "<path to outputted file>"
$out  = "$pathout\csv_merged_$(get-date -f MMddyyyy).csv"
$mergedData= Get-ChildItem $path -Exclude yesterday,output | Get-ChildItem  -recurse -Filter *csv  | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) } |  % {
    $file = $_.Name
    $fn = $_.FullName
    write-host $fn , $_.CreationTime
## get the contents of the files ,exclude columns and add columns 
     $Data =  Import-Csv -Path  $fn -Delimiter ',' | SELECT  *, @{Name = 'Filename'; Expression = {$file}} -ExcludeProperty ID 
   # get the headers 
    $header=  $Data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation  | Select-Object -First 1
   write-host $header
## convert the object and remove the column headers for each file
    $Data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation  | Select-Object -Skip 1 
    write-host 
    write-host '-----------------------' 
    }

# Prefix the header before the compiled data
$header, $mergedData  | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 $out
```

The missing piece was the ConvertTo_Csv which expanded the object.